# edit line in a text file

Tags: java, file-handling

i've tried this code that i found in the internet

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = "", oldtext = "";
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
            oldtext += line + "\n";

        }
        reader.close();
        // replace a word in a file
        //String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("drink", "Love");

        //To replace a line in a file
        String replace = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter what to replace: ");
        String toreplace = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter where to replace: ");
        String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll(replace, toreplace);

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file.txt");
        writer.append(newtext);writer.close();
```

but mine won't output like  this code will do. the output of this code is like this:

unedit:

```
jojo moyes
kim possible
dexter laboratory
```

edited: when i enter "mary" to edit "kim"

```
jojo moyes
mary possible
dexter laboratoty
```

but mine will be like this

```
jojo moyes
kim possible
dexter laboratoy
mary possible
```

mine tho had register before editing. and in the register there is also time that it will store something in the text file. and there goes the edit function if the user wants to edit something in the information that he entered (you get the picture)

EDITED: here's my code

```
public void Register_Edit_Info() throws IOException{
        FileWriter writeFile=new FileWriter("voters.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter outFile=new BufferedWriter(writeFile);
        File readFile=new File("voters.txt");   
        BufferedReader read=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readFile));

        String choice2;
        String [] secondMenu = {"Register", "Edit", "Delete", "Back"};

        do{
            choice2=(String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please choose:", "Election 2765", 1, null, secondMenu, secondMenu[0]);
            switch(choice2){
            case "Register":
                String [] menuGender={"Male", "Female"};
                String [] menuStatus={"Single", "Married", "Widow(er)", "Legally separated"};

                do{
                age=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Age: "));
                while(age<18){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voter should be 18 or above");
                    age=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Age: "));
                }
                name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Full Name: ");
                gender=(String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Gender:", "Election 2765", 1, null, menuGender, menuGender[0]);
                if(gender=="Male"){
                    gender="Male";
                }
                else{
                    gender="Female";
                }
                dBirth=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Date of Birth: ");
                pBirth=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Place of Birth: ");
                address=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Address\n(Province, City/Municipality, Barangay, House No./Street: ");
                status=(String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Civil Status:", "Election 2765", 1, null, menuStatus, menuStatus[0]);
                if(status=="Single"){
                    status="Single";
                }
                else if(status=="Married"){
                    spouse=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Spouse Name: ");
                    status="Married(Spouse: "+spouse+")";
                }
                else if(status=="Widow(er)"){
                    status="Widow(er)";
                }
                else{
                    status="Legally Separated";
                }
                citizenship=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Citizenship:");
                job=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Profession/Occupation: ");
                tin=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Tin Number: ");
                father=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Father's Full Name: ");
                mother=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Mother's Full Name: ");
                votersNumber++; 

                vNumber=Integer.toString(votersNumber);

                outFile.append(vNumber+"/"+name+"/"+age+"/"+gender+"/"+dBirth+"/"+pBirth+"/"+address+"/"+status+"/"+citizenship+"/"+job+"/"+father+"/"+mother);
                outFile.newLine();

                selectYN=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You are now registered. Do you want to register more?\n[1]Yes [2]No");
                }while(!"2".equals(selectYN));

                break;
            case "Edit":
                vNumForEdit=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter voters number: ");
                String line=null, oldtext="";

                while((line=read.readLine())!=null){
                    oldtext+=line+"\n";

                    String [] info=line.split("/");
                    if(info[0].matches(vNumForEdit)){
                        String [] forEditMenu={"Name", "Age", "Gender", "Date of Birth", "Place of Birth", "Address", "Civil Status", "Citizenship", "Profession/Occupation", "Father's Name", "Mother's Name"};
                        forEdit=(String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, line+"\n\nPlease select what you want to edit", "National Election 2765", 1, null, forEditMenu, forEditMenu[0]);
                        switch(forEdit){
                        case "Name":
                            oldName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter old name: ");
                            newName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new name: ");

                            String newText = oldtext.replaceAll(oldName, newName);
                            outFile.append(newText);                            
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            case "Delete":
                break;
            }
        }while(choice2!="Back");
        read.close();
        outFile.close();
    }
```

Comment: So, you have some code that shows some output, and the output is wrong. But we don't know: - what your code is, - what it's supposed to do, - what your inputs are. So how could we help?

Comment: Have you tried using writer.write(newtext) instead? Appending adds your new text at the end of the already existing text, whereas writing will overwrite the previous text. It does not seem to be the problem, but worth a shot nonetheless.

Comment: @JBNizet i already posted the code hehehe :)

Comment: @chalarangelo i tried it now but it is still the same

Answer (score 1):

This Answer is for the first portion of your question.(before edit).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,IOException {
        File file = new File("file.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = "", oldtext = "";
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
            oldtext += line + "\n";

        }
        reader.close();
        System.out.println(oldtext);
        // replace a word in a file
        //String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("drink", "Love");

        //To replace a line in a file
        String replace = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter what to replace: ");
        String toreplace = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter where to replace: ");
        String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll(replace, toreplace);

        System.out.println(newtext);
        java.io.FileWriter writer = new java.io.FileWriter("file1.txt");
        writer.write(newtext);
        writer.close();
    }
```

When first prompt open I write "kim" and where to replace , I write "marry" and the output like this. I think your code is fine except not to use `append()` for FileWriter. you should use `write()` method for FileWriter.

[image]

**EDIT:**
Use different file name (I don't know about if reading and writing operation occur for same file.) for `FileWriter` and for initialization you can use

```
FileWriter writeFile=new FileWriter("voters1.txt");
```

And let me know if the problems is solved.

Comment: i edited my question and i post my code their please check it because when i tried to use `write()` it is still the same. the one that you tried to run is the code that i fine in a site that works perfectly. but when i implement it in my code it won't work anymore

Comment: should i write another `FileWriter` or just changed the file name?

Comment: just change the name.

Comment: oh nothing happened :(